# Extract information from Google Earth Layer

Tags: kml, google-earth

I need to get the latitude and longitude of all the transportation locations. Google Earth has a transportation layer, can I export this layer information? Specifically I am looking for all the airport locations in the United States and to do some stuff with it in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can. These free or low cost mapping systems (desktop and online) have restrictive sub-licensing constrains from heir data providers.

For airports, have you tried the FAA? Also the Geonames database should have this information but I don't know how complete it is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export Google Earth's data layers but you can access many of the same public data sources that Google uses for its layers. There are a lot of data sources for airport locations.

Here is an online lookup service for airport codes which is updated and designated by the International Air Transport Association (IATA).

http://www.iata.org/index.htm

And here's a discussion listing several sources including a zip file with ICAO airports world-wide with 43,000+ in .CSV format (comma separated value).

http://www.airport-data.com/forums/topic4054.html

If the above resources aren't what you're looking for then search around and you'll find exactly what you need.